# Create a random string of a given cardinality

Tags: java, random, cardinality

Is there a builtin (or otherwise trivial) method of generating a random string in Java given a certain given cardinality?

E.g.,, `randStringCard(10,2)` would create a random string of length 10 but with only two possible unique values

`RandStringCard(1,26)` would generate a single character with 26 values, and `randStringCard(*,1)` would always generate the same output.

Comment: Can you give example outputs?

Comment: - randStringCard(1,1) would generate 'X' for example

- randStringCard(1,2) (length 1, cardinality 2) would generate either 'Y', or 'Z'

- randStringCard(2,2) (length 2, cardinality 2) would generate either AA, AB, BA or BB, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using `Random` and `nextInt(`*`<#differentChars>`*`)` to get an `int` in the range of different characters you want to support. Then you need to convert this number to a `String` and add it to the result, repeat "desiredLength" times.

To convert the number to a `String` you could do as follows:

```
if (n < 26)
  s += (char)('A' + n); // A-Z is used first
else if (n < 36)
  s += n - 26; // then 0-9
else
  s += ???; // symbols or lower case letters
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be useful

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
...
System.out.println(new BigInteger(50,  new SecureRandom()).toString(32));
```